# What is the fundamental assumption for using resampling methods?

Tags: time-series, cross-validation, bootstrap, assumptions, iid

Suppose that I observe a set of non-i.i.d. data (time series) $\mathcal{L} = \left\lbrace (y_{t}, x_{t}) \right\rbrace_{t=1}^{T}$ with $x_{t} = (x_{t1},\ldots,x_{tP})$ a real valued vector of $P$ inputs. Suppose for simplicity that the output and the inputs are stationary. I'm trying to model the relation between my output and my inputs using a Random Forest that I denote $\psi(., \theta)$, with $\theta$ a vector of parameters and hyperparameters.

I further assume that $$ (H1): ~~ \forall t, y_{t}=\psi(x_{t}, \theta) + \varepsilon_{t}$$

such that the $\left\lbrace \varepsilon_{t} \right\rbrace_{t=1}^{T}$ are i.i.d. with $\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon_{t}) = 0 $ and $\mathbb{V}(\varepsilon_{t}) = \sigma^{2} $. The disturbances and the inputs are assumed to be independant.

**Question1:** Knowing that the data are clearly not i.i.d., is $(H1)$ a sufficient condition to use K-fold cross validation ? Should the i.i.d. assumption relate to the data or the disturbances ?

According to the papers I read, it is necessary to have independent training and test sets. Yet, [Bergmeir, Hyndman & Koo (2018)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947317302384) argues that CV can be used as with i.i.d. data even if it involves using the future to predict the past.

**Question2:** Knowing that the data are stationary and that resampling overlapping blocks of data as in [Kunsch (1989)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2241719?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) doesn't generate independent training and test (out-of-bag) samples, is there an interest in using block-bootstrap methods for generating the bootstrap samples of the RF ?